# Getting warning when placing \hyperref inside \chapter

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I'm getting a warning on this line:

```
\chapter{\hyperref[ch:eng]{\conlang\ to English Dictionary}}
```

\conlang is a custom command defined like so:

```
\newcommand{\conlang}{Mbagu}
```

The warning is:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\@ifnextchar'
```

I don't understand this warning. The link works. How do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: `\chapter[\conlang{} to English Dictionary]{\hyperref[ch:eng]{\conlang{} to English Dictionary}}` might help.

Comment: @leandriis yeah, that worked! I'm guessing the issue was that it also tried to place the link in the table of contents?

Comment: Evidently, I wonder if `\protect\hyperref` would work?  There should be no reason why you can't put an \href in the TOC, so long as you don't expand it too soon.